# Jquery ajax call not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, cookies

i'm making an app to track different craft beers i've tasted. part of that is making an AJAX call to set a cookie in the uder's browser -- i'm json_encoding the list.beerList array and trying to store it in a cookie. for some reason, the cookie is getting set, but Firebug isn't registering an AJAX call being made. and even when i send something back, the success condition of the jquery AJAX function isn't firing. code below:

```
angular.module( 'beerList', [] ).controller( 'beerListController', function($scope) {
var list = this;

list.beerList = [];

angular.element(document).ready( function() {
    list.getCookie();
})

list.addBeer = function() {
    var beerEntered = $( '#beer' ).val();
    var breweryEntered = $( '#brewery' ).val();
    var abvEntered = $( '#abv' ).val();
    var notesEntered = $( '#notes' ).val();

    list.beerList.push( { beer: beerEntered, brewery: breweryEntered, abv: abvEntered, notes: notesEntered } );
    list.setCookie();
}

list.setCookie = function() {
    var string = JSON.stringify(list.beerList);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ABSOLUTE/PATH/TO/setCookie.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        data: {
            string: string
        },

        success: function(data) {
            alert('success!');
        }
    })
}

list.getCookie = function() {}
})
```

thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Where do you call `addBeer`?

Comment: Why don't you use AngularJ Ajax mechanism instead of jQuery AJAX?

Comment: Why do you call php to set a cookie? Angular can do that.

Comment: Please use $http service. Mixing angular and jQuery will not do any good for your app. It may serve as  a short fix for quick fix but sooner or later you will land into problems which will be very difficult to debug because you wont know when the digest cycle is triggered